# Can Landscape monitor the server it is hosted on?

Tags: landscape

I want to use Landscape to monitor a few of our servers, but I want to host Landscape on a server that I also want to manage. Can Landscape manage the server it is hosted on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can install the client software onto the same hardware as the Landscape server software to manage it.